# Getting the value of the previous index on an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have two character arrays here and my goal is to get the change of the two arrays and form a string of word.The idea is like getting the new played word in scrabble, wherein I also need to consider the character I used from the previous word.(am I saying it clear?).My problem here is that, I can get the OST but not the P...help please..

here's my code

```
Character[][] arr1 = new Character[4][4];
    arr1[0][0] = 'H';
    arr1[0][1] = 'E';
    arr1[0][2] = 'L';
    arr1[0][3] = 'P';
    arr1[1][0] = ' ';
    arr1[1][2] = ' ';
    arr1[1][3] = ' ';
    arr1[2][0] = ' ';
    arr1[2][1] = ' ';
    arr1[2][2] = ' ';
    arr1[2][3] = ' ';
    arr1[3][0] = ' ';
    arr1[3][1] = ' ';
    arr1[3][2] = ' ';
    arr1[3][3] = ' ';

    Character[][] arr2 = new Character[4][4];
    arr2[0][0] = 'H';
    arr2[0][1] = 'E';
    arr2[0][2] = 'L';
    arr2[0][3] = 'P';
    arr2[1][0] = ' ';
    arr2[1][2] = ' ';
    arr2[1][3] = 'O';
    arr2[2][0] = ' ';
    arr2[2][1] = ' ';
    arr2[2][2] = ' ';
    arr2[2][3] = 'S';
    arr2[3][0] = ' ';
    arr2[3][1] = ' ';
    arr2[3][2] = ' ';
    arr2[3][3] = 'T';

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            if(arr1[i][j]!=arr2[i][j]){
                s = arr2[i][j];
                t = Character.toString(s);
                out = builder.append(t).toString();
            }
        }
    }
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            output.setText(out);
            }
    });
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: The only differences between the two arrays is OST, so why should the result contain a 'P'?

Comment: When the board is pretty full, there are situations, where you form several words by adding characters. What output do you expect then?

Comment: @Jermaine Xu ....it is because my goal is to get the whole word...just like in scrabble.when there's new word added to the board, the new word contains a letter from the previous word...

Comment: @Henry my goal here is to get the word POST from the two arrays...I am only getting OST from my program above..

Comment: If you're comparing the difference between the two arrays, how is the program supposed to know which letter you want to keep from the first array? You need some sort of flag or index to instruct the code to include a certain letter.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is that you are writing code too early.  Get some paper.  Design your algorithm(s).  Test on paper.  Then come back to the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The Reason you cannot get "P" is your condition is not valid where arr1[0][3]!=arr2[0][3] is false. In this case condition check if("P"!= "P") which is false, so the loop ignore the condition.

But "O", "S", and "T" compares with " ", so it will append "OST"

Maybe you can work around from here, or explain more about the requirement.

Comment: @Anuardha Namal ..I need to have two arrays so that I can compare the contents and get the new value added into it.,I need to get the whole word for scoring and checking the validity of word from a database..Just like in a scrabble game, i need to get the whole word..and this is the only way I know,if there's other way can you teach me how to do it?..thanks..